# bash script controlling ffmpeg to convert from mkv

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

Help me debugs this script to create control ffmpeg from a bash script.

```
for f in $FILES
do
    INPUT_MOVIE=`basename "${f%.*}.mkv"`
    OUTPUT_MOVIE=${MOVIE:1}
    OUTPUT_MOVIE=${OUTPUT_MOVIE:0:2}") processed "${OUTPUT_MOVIE:2}
    /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i $INPUT_MOVIE -map 0:0 -vcodec copy -map 0:1 -acodec copy $OUTPUT_MOVIE
    /usr/bin/sleep 3
done
```

I've tried attaching the sleep but the processes seems to start to pile up. Is there a way to do them sequentially so that one video is processed after the other?

Comment: What you show should run one after the other. What makes you think the processes pile up? Could it just be that `ffmpeg` launches multiple instances of itself?

Comment: what, exactly, is in `$FILES`? (and don't just say "filenames", that's obvious.  Show some examples, add them to your question).  Spaces, newlines, globbing characters?   Use an array.  Also, always **double-quote ALL your variables**.  And why the weird usage of both `basename` AND `${f%.*}`?

Comment: and where is `$MOVIE` defined?  do you mean `INPUT_MOVIE` there?   BTW, if you run something in the background and later want to wait until it's finished before doing something else, don't use `sleep`.  use `wait`.  that's what it's for.  see `help wait` in bash for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for your purposes?

`for i in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$i" … ;done`